# Is faking a question the only way an user can post an interesting small tutorial?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If the goal of stack* sites are to become a FAQ; why not to allow an user to be able to post tutorials and associate a list of possible questions to it?

Comment: related: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195/long-and-cohesive-to-short-and-modular

Answer (score 10):

When a question gets asked many, many times, we will often ask a users to create an awesome, canonical answer so that all the numerous duplicate questions can finally, once and for all, be referred to the *one* canonical answer.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

But posting a tutorial is a bit awkward in this Q&A format. I don't think it will go over that well, in and of itself. Perhaps it would be better to provide the best possible answer to the question; if that included *also* linking to a tutorial appearing elsewhere on the web, that would be kindly regarded as all the more helpful. But the *answer* should reside in the text of the message.

As for "faking" a question as an excuse for posting something; it is certainly allowed, but how it is received depends on the context. If you have a helpful answer to a problem you have actually faced, it might be seen as helpful. But if you were to create a tutorial and forced a question to point to it, that could be construed more along the lines of spam and might not be received as well. The guideline I would use is to make sure the content is very organic to the site. It's best to wait for the occasion of answering an *actual* question, but failing that opportunity, make sure your *faked* question part of a long line of otherwise useful contributions to the site.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Do you have any links to SO questions that have been merged into a single canonical answer? (A canonical canonical answer in other words.)

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall: Nothing specific I can find at the moment. I know this was recently a big issue on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), where users were sick of the same few questions being asked over and over, so they developed a set of canonical answers to those questions. See, for example, [this discussion](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/973/sick-of-unprofessional-questions/1032#1032)

Answer (score 6):

One downside of tutorials is that they take a lot of space so other answers can't be seen. It is just as useful to post a tutorial on a blog and link to it where relevant.

Also tutorials are more general and often not suited to specific questions. If it is a relevant answer to a question then I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: +1 I prefer a concise answer that highlights the key idea(s) that led to the solution over a tutorial style (do this, then that, then...). [Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-do-i-access-arcobjects-from-python/110#110) is an example that I think balances step-by-step with key ideas, while [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/how-to-prototype-gis-workflows-in-sketchflow/2428#2428) is definitely too long. And, full disclosure, I sometimes tend to be [too wordy myself](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195/long-and-cohesive-to-short-and-modular).

Comment: I just stumbled across Spatial Analysis Online. http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/output/  Despite its name, it doesn't really offer spatial analysis.  However it is a good site edited by experts.  If they would provide finer-grained urls to their topics it seems like their content could be driven by Q&A topics from gis.se.  Perhaps a hybrid of knol and wikipedia.